# Laravel validation with input field as array "title[]" throws always the same error

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

No matter which validation rule i brake as long as i have an array notation in input name like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('titile', '* Eventname: ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
  {!! Form::text('title[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
</div>
```

i get this error:

[image]

I have tried to use simple plain html input like this

`<input type="text" name="title[]" />`

and even like this

`{!! Form::text('title', null, ['name' => 'title[]','class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}`

But nothing works.

Only if i make the input field without array notation [] the validation works properly...

my validation rule is this

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|min:2',
    ]);
```

I don't know what else to do, if anyone had similar problem please help.

UPDATE:

i have tried it like this now with only one form input:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('title', '* Eventname: ', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        {!! Form::text('title', null, ['name' => 'title[]','class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'placeholder' => 'z.B. Deutscher Filmpreis']) !!}
    </div>
```

-

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [

    ];

    foreach($this->get('title') as $key => $val)
    {
        $rules['title.'.$key] = 'numeric';
    }


    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: Its because you can't insert an array in it, it wants a string. if you want many  titles under each other or a select you should consider using a loop to generate them.

Comment: can you describe this with little more details? do you mean i should use variable names without [ ] in my form or how?

Comment: Why do you have a validator on a title/label? That validator should be on input fields. And also why do you want to use an array on a single item instance? please explain the goal you want to achieve so I can tell you how to solve it.

Comment: The title field is only for example....i have other fields that are important....but it seems to me that the problem was with empty brackets [ ], in order to have an array you need to put something inside for example [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i finally solved this. In Laravel 5.3 something is changed and you can't put empty array brackets for field name.

You must declare indices inside...for example:

this doesn't work

```
{!! Form::text('title[]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

but this works

```
{!! Form::text('title[0]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}
```

#### UPDATE

So after solving this now i know that if you put empty [ ] brackets this will work if you have multiple input fields with same name...but if you put empty brackets and you have an option to add new fields dynamically like i did...then that single field with empty array brackets will fail because you actually don't have an array...and you must put [0] some indices inside...
and then it works

Answer (score 1):

Write your validation in individual request file. This ('title' => 'required|min:2') validation does not work for array input. Try this technique for dynamic field validation.

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [

  ];

  foreach($this->request->get('title') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['title.'.$key] = 'required|min:2';
  }

  return $rules;
}
```

Comment: i will try to implement this and then i will accept your answer if it works

Comment: I tried this and i still get the same error. i will update my question so you can see and maybe help me further

Comment: I don't get it how can he do that in this video??? https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-2/episodes/4

Comment: Don't put blank array like title[] use like below

Comment: {!! Form::text('title['.$id.']', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) !!}

Answer (score 0):

Very Good example at laravel news site.
https://laravel-news.com/2015/11/laravel-5-2-a-look-at-whats-coming/